# How can I change the VB.NET application connection string after deployment?

Tags: vb.net, deployment, connection-string, app-config

I have written a VB.NET application and created a setup file to install the same on the target machine. An ODBC connection is used to connect to SQL Server instance through a DSN.

My development computer used Integrated Security whereas the target computer uses SQL Authentication which requires me to hard code the credentials in the connection string while building the setup file.

I have previously looked up for solutions, but they require one to define the credentials every time the application is run. I have seen an application that requests the credentials the first time it is run or if the connection is unsuccessful, but unfortunately could not retrieve the source code for the same.

Any guidance on similar lines would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe by using a simple configuration file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Answer (score 0):

Add application settings of string type with user scope for the user name and password, lets say username & userpass. Let the User save these values the first time they run your app.  Then just incorporate the My.Settings.username and My.Settings.userpass into your connection string.

To save the settings:

```
My.Settings.username = txt_user.text
My.Settings.Save()
```

This way the user can change the username & password if required without you having to update your code.

Comment: I have been able to write code to modify the config file as I required. But the configuration cannot be changed if the program is installed in the default location i.e. C:\Program Files.

Comment: That is why I suggested using application settings instead.  These settings can be changed on the fly as needed.